# Afresco Web Editor (AWE) vs Alfresco Web Quick Start (WQS)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-wqs

I am referring the Alfresco [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0) and I have already gone through the Alfresco Web Quick Start. At the end of reading the docs I am still confuse that **What is conceptual different between Afresco Web Editor (AWE) vs Alfresco Web Quick Start (WQS)**? When should we use each of them? Any special use-case?

Answer (score 3):

AWE is only a module used by WQS for in place editing of the articles.

For example, AWE does not know anything about collections, live site and editor site, publishing, navigations, etc...

The templates of an article in WQS are written using tags that AWE can interprets to show the editor form in the expected section of an article.

[This article](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Quick_Start_Developer_Guide) is the best guide to learn what you need to start developing with WCMQS. It has also some good graphs that describes how AWE is integrated in WCMQS.